# Avoiding fatal crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, crash

I have been debugging an app for a while and am ready to upload it to app store.  However, I still get occasional crashes that are hard to duplicate or debug--for example when pushing buttons in weird sequences.  If I write these sequences down, I can debug but inevitably it happens when I haven't written it down and these can be difficult to replicate.

I know I need to just call it a day and leave future bug fixes for next release. I have removed all the abort() statements I had in testing.  However, occasionally rather than getting a crash that lets you just close the app and reopen, I get one that makes it impossible to open the app without reinstalling.  For example, this just happened, with a

> 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x174a41b90> was mutated while being enumerated.'

This resulted from switching VCs during a background sync to the cloud.

I can live with crashes where you just need to reopen but not with ones that render the app unusable. Are there any guidelines for types of crashes to help you focus on the really fatal ones?

Or is there anything you can do to keep crashes from bricking app?

Comment: Solve the underlying cause. Ensure your code is thread-safe.

Comment: Seems like an issue from a race condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just fix this problem. Since you have this crashlog with that error message, you know which method can raise the problem, so you've got a good head start on fixing it, even if the problem manifests itself inconsistently and/or in a variety of ways.

But the occasional crash may not seem like too much of an inconvenience to you, but it is the quickest way to 1-star reviews and unhappy customers. I suspect you will quickly regret distributing an app with known, easily reproduced crashes.

But, a few observations:

1. It sounds like your background update process is mutating your model objects used by the main thread.

   - If possible, I'd suggest being careful to simply do not change any of your model objects in the background thread, but rather populate a local variable and when you're ready to update the UI accordingly, dispatch both the model update and UI refresh to the main thread.
   - If you cannot do this for some reason, you have to synchronize all interaction of model updates with some mechanism such as locks, GCD serial queue, reader-writer model, etc. This is slightly more complicated approach, but can be done.
2. I would advise temporarily editing your target's "scheme" and turn on the thread sanitizer:

   [image]

   It may possibly help you identify and more easily reproduce these sorts of problems. And the more easily you can reproduce the problem, the more easily you will be able to fix the issue.
3. You say:

   > Or is there anything you can do to keep crashes from bricking app?

   It sounds like the "save" operation is somehow leaving the results in persistent storage in an internally inconsistent manner. Any one of the following would help, though I'd suggest you do all three if possible):

   - At the risk of repeating myself, fix the crash (it's always better to eliminate the source of the problem than try to program around manifestations of the problem);
   - Depending upon how you're saving your results, you may be able to employ an [`atomic`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata.writingoptions/1411764-atomic) save operation, so that if it fails half way, it won't leave it in an inconsistent state; we can't advise how you should do that without seeing code snippet illustrating how you're saving the results, but it's often an option;
   - Make sure that, if the "load" process that reads the persistent storage can fail, that it does so gracefully, rather than crashing; see if you can get it in this state where the app is failing during start-up, and then carefully debug what's going on in the start-up process that is causing the app to fail with this particular set of data in persistent storage. In the "devices" section, there is an option to download the data associated with an app, so you can carefully diagnose what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for this very thorough answer.  With respect to your first paragraph is there a way to tell what method caused the crash from the error message above.  Knowing the spot of the crash would help with debugging.

Comment: If you can manifest the crash while running the app in the debugger (either on device or on simulator), that's easiest, as you can look at the stack trace right in Xcode. If you're stuck with crash logs, you may need to "symbolicate" them (translating cryptic addresses to lines of code; see [TN2151](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)).

Comment: I turned on thread sanitizer and pause on issues and sure enough, the app is pausing showing just a black screen.  However, not seeing anything in the console to suggest why.  Where should I be looking?

Comment: "Blank screen" in the app? That's fine. We care less about the app than we do the stack traces in Xcode. It's going to be impossible for me to walk you through this in comments, but I might suggest watching WWDC 2016 video [Thread Sanitizer and Static Analysis](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/412/) or WWDC 2017 [Finding Bugs using Xcode Runtime Tools](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/406/). I think those include practical demonstrations on how to use the tool. Sorry I can't help more. ;(

Comment: Ok.  Thx, I watched the video and it's very helpful. No issues appearing for my app but I can't try everything as app does not launch in simulator. 
I will keep working on that.  Thx.